# Where to put methods, inside parent or child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a website in React, and am wondering what the better practice is in terms of placing JS functions. If I have a method `doSomething()` and am utilizing `doSomething()` in several instances of a component, would it be better to place `doSomething()` in the child component, or parent? If it's in the parent component, it makes it a bit harder to follow the code, whereas if it's in the child component, there are multiple identical methods that are retrieved (i.e. one for each instance of the child component called).

i.e. is the this better:

```
export default class Parent extends Component{

    doSomething(){...}

    render(){
        return(
            <Child />
            <Child />
            <Child />
        ) }

}
```

or this:

```
export default class Parent extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <Child />
            <Child />
            <Child />
        ) }

}


class Child extends Component{

    doSomething(){...}

    render(){
        return(
            <p>This is the child component</p>
        )

    }

}
```

Comment: put it in the child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only used among Child instances, I'd place the method in the Child class.

"whereas if it's in the child component, there are multiple identical methods that are retrieved."

The way you've declared doSomething() in child above does not make it an instance method.

The `doSomething()` method will end up property of the Child prototype & its reference will be shared by all instances.

For doSomething to end up an instance method you'd have to define something like `this.doSomething = function(){...` in the Child constructor.

(another exception is if you declare doSomething() a `static` method of the Child class' constructor).